# Click on each onclick where the onclick attribute changes randomly

Tags: javascript, onclick, casperjs

I need to scrap a web and click on multiple tabs on the web.
I'm checking the onclick's attribute value changes randomly and I can't find a way to select each tab. The onclick attribute are:
    onclick="clickDashboard('889113733777776')"
    onclick="clickDashboard('894967889413237')"

This is the html fragment I want to try to click on each tab. I get it with getHTML() casprjs function, if I try to copy from source code (crtl+U) I just can see javascript code. You can also see how li tag class is 'activetab' to indicate which tab is displayed. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17inSduz_byO1TSqH2XOwvFwuGGTBpm-n/view?usp=sharing) link to full html source file

```
<!--TEMPLATES-->
    <ul id="tabul">
        <li id="litab" class="ntabs add"><a href="" id="addtab" class="osx">+</a></li>
        <li id="litab" class="add rightAlign setting-item">
            <img src="/Content/images/icons/expand-24x24.png" class="out-triggerer gray" onclick="fullScreen()">            
        </li>        
        <li id="default-report-export" class="rightAlign">
            <a href="/report/defaultExport" download="">
                <input type="image" src="/Content/images/icons/excel.gif" value="Excel" title="Export default report">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="default-report-export" class="rightAlign">
            <a href="/report/defaultExport?isPdf=true" download="">
                <input type="image" src="/Content/images/export-pdf-24x24.png" value="Excel" title="Export default report">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="dbTab_889113733777776" class="ntabs addedTab activeTab">
            <span id="dbTabLabel_889113733777776" class="dashTitle" onclick="clickDashboard('889113733777776')">Dashboard EUR</span>
            <span id="dbTabSettings_889113733777776" class="settingsContainer dashSettings" style="">
                <div id="topnav" class="topnav">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="signin" onclick="toggleTabSettingsMenu('889113733777776',true);">
                        <span><img src="/Content/Images/icon_gear.png" alt="Edit"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <fieldset id="dbTabSettingsMenu_889113733777776" class="dashSettings-menu">
                    <ul class="dashboardEditMenu">
                        <img src="/Content/images/close.png" onclick="toggleTabSettingsMenu('889113733777776',false);" alt="tooltip" style="position:absolute;right:2px;top:2px;border:0;">
                        <li class="dashboardEditMenuList">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addWidget" onclick="toggleLeftUpdatePanelMenu(true);"> Añadir widgets</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dashboardEditMenuList">
                             <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeDash" onclick="deleteDashboard('889113733777776')"> Borrar este dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li id="dbTab_894967889413237" class="ntabs addedTab">
            <span id="dbTabLabel_894967889413237" class="dashTitle" onclick="clickDashboard('894967889413237')">Dashboard USD</span>
            <span id="dbTabSettings_894967889413237" class="settingsContainer dashSettings" style="display:none;">
                <div id="topnav" class="topnav">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="signin" onclick="toggleTabSettingsMenu('894967889413237',true);">
                        <span><img src="/Content/Images/icon_gear.png" alt="Edit"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <fieldset id="dbTabSettingsMenu_894967889413237" class="dashSettings-menu"> 
                    <ul class="dashboardEditMenu">
                        <img src="/Content/images/close.png" onclick="toggleTabSettingsMenu('894967889413237',false);" alt="tooltip" style="position:absolute;right:2px;top:2px;border:0;">
                        ...
                   </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying select each tab and make a screenshot with this code:

```
//Wait to be redirected to the Home page, and then make a screenshot
casper.then(function(){
    casper.wait(5000, function(){
        this.capture('home.png');
        var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=dbTabLabel]');
        var i;
        console.log('Tabs found: ' + tabs.length);
        for(i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            tabs.click()
            var name = 'tab' + i + '.png'
            this.capture(name); //Make a screenshot for each tab
        }
    })    
});
```

But it seems that it doesn't select any tab because output is `Tabs found: 0`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using

```
casper.each(tabs, function(self, tab){

};
```

Instead a `for`. Also, in the `querySelectorAll` use a more generic selector like `ul#tabul li`. I tried using a for loop inside a casperjs script and always got an error, using each and more generic selectors worked for me every time!

Comment: thanks, but I'm still can't select those li blocks. I'm tested with a more generic selector as you say and tabs is always null. I'm edited original question to add the full html file that I get after login and save with getHTML() casperjs function. I don't know if my problem happens only when I'm scraping "on fly" because of some embedded script. i'm lost with that.